# Why is SQL Server full-text search returning one number but not other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, contains

I have An Agreement with the Columns AgreementID int, and BaseAgreementNumber NVARCHAR(20) which contains the following data.

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| AgreementID | BaseAgreementNumber  |
+-------------+----------------------+
|      181672 |      365141240514359 |
|      179078 |                15943 |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

Record ID 181672 is not showing up in the results while record ID 179078 is.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

The is Table created using following script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Agreement](
[AgreementID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[BaseAgreementNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Agreement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [AgreementID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And The full text catalog created as follows

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Agreement] KEY INDEX [PK_Agreement] ON ([AIMIEFTS]) WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO)
GO

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Agreement] ADD ([BaseAgreementNumber] LANGUAGE [Neutral])
GO
```

The following query returns no rows

```
select * from Agreement where CONTAINS(BaseAgreementNumber, '365141240514359')
```

But this query returns rows.

```
select * from Agreement where CONTAINS(BaseAgreementNumber, '15943')
```

Comment: does the query `select * from Agreement where CONTAINS(BaseAgreementNumber, '14359')` produces any result?

Comment: No that dosen't return anything, i've also now set the stoplist to <off> to see if that has any effect but it dosnt.